# How to change rotation handler icon in mxgraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mxgraph

i'm facing bit difficulty to change `rotation` handler icon

**below image show you:**

[image]

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. click on the box
2. Observe `rotation` handler will appear.

i want to change above rotation handler with some other icon.

**below is my code:**

```html
<!--
  Copyright (c) 2006-2014, JGraph Ltd
  
  Handles example for mxGraph. This example demonstrates using mxHandle to change custom styles interactively.
-->
<html>
<head>
 <title>Handles example for mxGraph</title>

 <!-- Sets the basepath for the library if not in same directory -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
   mxBasePath = 'https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/src';
 </script>

  <!-- Loads and initializes the library -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/src/js/mxClient.js"></script>

 <!-- Example code -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function MyShape()
  {
   mxCylinder.call(this);
  };
 
  mxUtils.extend(MyShape, mxCylinder);

  MyShape.prototype.defaultPos1 = 20;
  MyShape.prototype.defaultPos2 = 60;
  
  MyShape.prototype.getLabelBounds = function(rect)
  {
    var pos1 = mxUtils.getValue(this.style, 'pos1', this.defaultPos1) * this.scale;
    var pos2 = mxUtils.getValue(this.style, 'pos2', this.defaultPos2) * this.scale;

    return new mxRectangle(rect.x, rect.y + pos1, rect.width, Math.min(rect.height, pos2) - Math.max(0, pos1));
  };
  
  MyShape.prototype.redrawPath = function(path, x, y, w, h, isForeground)
  {
    var pos1 = mxUtils.getValue(this.style, 'pos1', this.defaultPos1);
    var pos2 = mxUtils.getValue(this.style, 'pos2', this.defaultPos2);
    
   if (isForeground)
   {
    if (pos1 < h)
    {
     path.moveTo(0, pos1);
     path.lineTo(w, pos1);
    }
    
    if (pos2 < h)
    {
     path.moveTo(0, pos2);
     path.lineTo(w, pos2);
    }
   }
   else
   {
    path.rect(0, 0, w, h);
   }
  };

  mxCellRenderer.registerShape('myShape', MyShape);
  
  mxVertexHandler.prototype.createCustomHandles = function()
  {
   if (this.state.style['shape'] == 'myShape')
   {
    // Implements the handle for the first divider
    var firstHandle = new mxHandle(this.state);
    
    firstHandle.getPosition = function(bounds)
    {
     var pos2 = Math.max(0, Math.min(bounds.height, parseFloat(mxUtils.getValue(this.state.style, 'pos2', MyShape.prototype.defaultPos2))));
     var pos1 = Math.max(0, Math.min(pos2, parseFloat(mxUtils.getValue(this.state.style, 'pos1', MyShape.prototype.defaultPos1))));

     return new mxPoint(bounds.getCenterX(), bounds.y + pos1);
    };
    
    firstHandle.setPosition = function(bounds, pt)
    {
     var pos2 = Math.max(0, Math.min(bounds.height, parseFloat(mxUtils.getValue(this.state.style, 'pos2', MyShape.prototype.defaultPos2))));
     
     this.state.style['pos1'] = Math.round(Math.max(0, Math.min(pos2, pt.y - bounds.y)));
    };
    
    firstHandle.execute = function()
    {
     this.copyStyle('pos1');
    }

    firstHandle.ignoreGrid = true;
    
    // Implements the handle for the second divider
    var secondHandle = new mxHandle(this.state);
    
    secondHandle.getPosition = function(bounds)
    {
     var pos1 = Math.max(0, Math.min(bounds.height, parseFloat(mxUtils.getValue(this.state.style, 'pos1', MyShape.prototype.defaultPos1))));
     var pos2 = Math.max(pos1, Math.min(bounds.height, parseFloat(mxUtils.getValue(this.state.style, 'pos2', MyShape.prototype.defaultPos2))));
     
     return new mxPoint(bounds.getCenterX(), bounds.y + pos2);
    };
    
    secondHandle.setPosition = function(bounds, pt)
    {
     var pos1 = Math.max(0, Math.min(bounds.height, parseFloat(mxUtils.getValue(this.state.style, 'pos1', MyShape.prototype.defaultPos1))));
          
     this.state.style['pos2'] = Math.round(Math.max(pos1, Math.min(bounds.height, pt.y - bounds.y)));
    };
    
    secondHandle.execute = function()
    {
     this.copyStyle('pos2');
    }

    secondHandle.ignoreGrid = true;

    return [firstHandle, secondHandle];
   }
   
   return null;
  };
  
  mxVertexHandler.prototype.livePreview = true;
  mxVertexHandler.prototype.rotationEnabled = true;
  
  // Program starts here. Creates a sample graph in the
  // DOM node with the specified ID. This function is invoked
  // from the onLoad event handler of the document (see below).
  function main(container)
  {
   // Checks if the browser is supported
   if (!mxClient.isBrowserSupported())
   {
    // Displays an error message if the browser is not supported.
    mxUtils.error('Browser is not supported!', 200, false);
   }
   else
   {
    // Disables the built-in context menu
    mxEvent.disableContextMenu(container);
    
    // Creates the graph inside the given container
    var graph = new mxGraph(container);
    graph.setCellsCloneable(true);
    graph.setHtmlLabels(true);
    graph.setPanning(true);
    graph.centerZoom = false;

    // Enables rubberband selection
    new mxRubberband(graph);

    // Gets the default parent for inserting new cells. This
    // is normally the first child of the root (ie. layer 0).
    var parent = graph.getDefaultParent();
        
    // Adds cells to the model in a single step
    graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
    try
    {
     var v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
      20, 20, 240, 120, 'shape=myShape;whiteSpace=wrap;overflow=hidden;pos1=30;pos2=80;');
    }
    finally
    {
     // Updates the display
     graph.getModel().endUpdate();
    }

    document.body.appendChild(mxUtils.button('+', function()
    {
     graph.zoomIn();
    }));
    document.body.appendChild(mxUtils.button('-', function()
    {
     graph.zoomOut();
    }));
   }
  };
 </script>
</head>

<!-- Page passes the container for the graph to the program -->
<body onload="main(document.getElementById('graphContainer'))">

 <!-- Creates a container for the graph with a grid wallpaper -->
 <div id="graphContainer"
  style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;width:621px;height:441px;background:url('editors/images/grid.gif');cursor:default;">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change rotation handler appearance you have to override [`createSizerShape`](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/blob/7af5a44c5b2d8a4d0fc56d3eebc964c3ca8b82de/javascript/src/js/handler/mxVertexHandler.js#L459) function in `mxVertexHandler`, and change part about rotation handle(`if (index == mxEvent.ROTATION_HANDLE)`).

It have to return shape, originally it create `mxEllipse`. If you want to use custom image you can use `mxImageShape` For example:

```js
let imgSrc = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a';
mxVertexHandler.prototype.createSizerShape = function(bounds, index, fillColor)
{
    if (this.handleImage != null)
    {
        bounds = new mxRectangle(bounds.x, bounds.y, this.handleImage.width, this.handleImage.height);
        var shape = new mxImageShape(bounds, this.handleImage.src);

        // Allows HTML rendering of the images
        shape.preserveImageAspect = false;

        return shape;
    }
    else if (index == mxEvent.ROTATION_HANDLE)
    {
        bounds = new mxRectangle(bounds.x, bounds.y, 20, 20);
        var shape = new mxImageShape(bounds, imgSrc);

        // Allows HTML rendering of the images
        shape.preserveImageAspect = false;

        return shape;
    }
    else
    {
        return new mxRectangleShape(bounds, fillColor || mxConstants.HANDLE_FILLCOLOR, mxConstants.HANDLE_STROKECOLOR);
    }
};
```

So your code will look like this:

```html
<!--
  Copyright (c) 2006-2014, JGraph Ltd
  
  Handles example for mxGraph. This example demonstrates using mxHandle to change custom styles interactively.
-->
<html>
<head>
 <title>Handles example for mxGraph</title>

 <!-- Sets the basepath for the library if not in same directory -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
   mxBasePath = 'https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/src';
 </script>

  <!-- Loads and initializes the library -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/src/js/mxClient.js"></script>

 <!-- Example code -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function MyShape()
  {
   mxCylinder.call(this);
  };
 
  mxUtils.extend(MyShape, mxCylinder);

  MyShape.prototype.defaultPos1 = 20;
  MyShape.prototype.defaultPos2 = 60;
  
  MyShape.prototype.getLabelBounds = function(rect)
  {
    var pos1 = mxUtils.getValue(this.style, 'pos1', this.defaultPos1) * this.scale;
    var pos2 = mxUtils.getValue(this.style, 'pos2', this.defaultPos2) * this.scale;

    return new mxRectangle(rect.x, rect.y + pos1, rect.width, Math.min(rect.height, pos2) - Math.max(0, pos1));
  };
  
  MyShape.prototype.redrawPath = function(path, x, y, w, h, isForeground)
  {
    var pos1 = mxUtils.getValue(this.style, 'pos1', this.defaultPos1);
    var pos2 = mxUtils.getValue(this.style, 'pos2', this.defaultPos2);
    
   if (isForeground)
   {
    if (pos1 < h)
    {
     path.moveTo(0, pos1);
     path.lineTo(w, pos1);
    }
    
    if (pos2 < h)
    {
     path.moveTo(0, pos2);
     path.lineTo(w, pos2);
    }
   }
   else
   {
    path.rect(0, 0, w, h);
   }
  };

  mxCellRenderer.registerShape('myShape', MyShape);
  
  mxVertexHandler.prototype.createCustomHandles = function()
  {
   if (this.state.style['shape'] == 'myShape')
   {
    // Implements the handle for the first divider
    var firstHandle = new mxHandle(this.state);
    
    firstHandle.getPosition = function(bounds)
    {
     var pos2 = Math.max(0, Math.min(bounds.height, parseFloat(mxUtils.getValue(this.state.style, 'pos2', MyShape.prototype.defaultPos2))));
     var pos1 = Math.max(0, Math.min(pos2, parseFloat(mxUtils.getValue(this.state.style, 'pos1', MyShape.prototype.defaultPos1))));

     return new mxPoint(bounds.getCenterX(), bounds.y + pos1);
    };
    
    firstHandle.setPosition = function(bounds, pt)
    {
     var pos2 = Math.max(0, Math.min(bounds.height, parseFloat(mxUtils.getValue(this.state.style, 'pos2', MyShape.prototype.defaultPos2))));
     
     this.state.style['pos1'] = Math.round(Math.max(0, Math.min(pos2, pt.y - bounds.y)));
    };
    
    firstHandle.execute = function()
    {
     this.copyStyle('pos1');
    }

    firstHandle.ignoreGrid = true;
    
    // Implements the handle for the second divider
    var secondHandle = new mxHandle(this.state);
    
    secondHandle.getPosition = function(bounds)
    {
     var pos1 = Math.max(0, Math.min(bounds.height, parseFloat(mxUtils.getValue(this.state.style, 'pos1', MyShape.prototype.defaultPos1))));
     var pos2 = Math.max(pos1, Math.min(bounds.height, parseFloat(mxUtils.getValue(this.state.style, 'pos2', MyShape.prototype.defaultPos2))));
     
     return new mxPoint(bounds.getCenterX(), bounds.y + pos2);
    };
    
    secondHandle.setPosition = function(bounds, pt)
    {
     var pos1 = Math.max(0, Math.min(bounds.height, parseFloat(mxUtils.getValue(this.state.style, 'pos1', MyShape.prototype.defaultPos1))));
          
     this.state.style['pos2'] = Math.round(Math.max(pos1, Math.min(bounds.height, pt.y - bounds.y)));
    };
    
    secondHandle.execute = function()
    {
     this.copyStyle('pos2');
    }

    secondHandle.ignoreGrid = true;

    return [firstHandle, secondHandle];
   }
   
   return null;
  };
  
  mxVertexHandler.prototype.livePreview = true;
  mxVertexHandler.prototype.rotationEnabled = true;
  let imgSrc = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a';
  mxVertexHandler.prototype.createSizerShape = function(bounds, index, fillColor)
  {
       if (this.handleImage != null)
   {
        bounds = new mxRectangle(bounds.x, bounds.y, this.handleImage.width, this.handleImage.height);
        var shape = new mxImageShape(bounds, this.handleImage.src);

        // Allows HTML rendering of the images
        shape.preserveImageAspect = false;

        return shape;
   }
   else if (index == mxEvent.ROTATION_HANDLE)
   {
        bounds = new mxRectangle(bounds.x, bounds.y, 20, 20);
    var shape = new mxImageShape(bounds, imgSrc);
 
    // Allows HTML rendering of the images
    shape.preserveImageAspect = false;

    return shape;
   }
   else
   {
        return new mxRectangleShape(bounds, fillColor || mxConstants.HANDLE_FILLCOLOR, mxConstants.HANDLE_STROKECOLOR);
   }
  };
  // Program starts here. Creates a sample graph in the
  // DOM node with the specified ID. This function is invoked
  // from the onLoad event handler of the document (see below).
  function main(container)
  {
   // Checks if the browser is supported
   if (!mxClient.isBrowserSupported())
   {
    // Displays an error message if the browser is not supported.
    mxUtils.error('Browser is not supported!', 200, false);
   }
   else
   {
    // Disables the built-in context menu
    mxEvent.disableContextMenu(container);
    
    // Creates the graph inside the given container
    var graph = new mxGraph(container);
    graph.setCellsCloneable(true);
    graph.setHtmlLabels(true);
    graph.setPanning(true);
    graph.centerZoom = false;

    // Enables rubberband selection
    new mxRubberband(graph);

    // Gets the default parent for inserting new cells. This
    // is normally the first child of the root (ie. layer 0).
    var parent = graph.getDefaultParent();
        
    // Adds cells to the model in a single step
    graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
    try
    {
     var v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
      20, 20, 240, 120, 'shape=myShape;whiteSpace=wrap;overflow=hidden;pos1=30;pos2=80;');
    }
    finally
    {
     // Updates the display
     graph.getModel().endUpdate();
    }

    document.body.appendChild(mxUtils.button('+', function()
    {
     graph.zoomIn();
    }));
    document.body.appendChild(mxUtils.button('-', function()
    {
     graph.zoomOut();
    }));
   }
  };
 </script>
</head>

<!-- Page passes the container for the graph to the program -->
<body onload="main(document.getElementById('graphContainer'))">

 <!-- Creates a container for the graph with a grid wallpaper -->
 <div id="graphContainer"
  style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;width:621px;height:441px;background:url('editors/images/grid.gif');cursor:default;">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much!!, can i use **image** instead of `shape`, please help me with **image**

Comment: I didn't get any response from you,  please produce a snippet with **image icon**.  Please help me.

Comment: Hi **Godric**  i'm struck with your solution, please have a look at this one https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/VOxBmB, if you tell i will ask this one as separate question here. but **Please have a look on this**, and reply me. Thank you.

Comment: All you need to do is to change if blocks order, first check and handle rotation handle (`if (index == mxEvent.ROTATION_HANDLE)` and then use default image (`else if (this.handleImage != null)`)

Comment: i din't understood, please show me once, thanks in advance!!